# Eddystone URL Issues

Tags: url, dns, eddystone

I am trying to simply display a URL in the Chrome Tab in an iOS device. I have an Eddystone Beacon with the URL configured that I want to use, however it is not coming up in the Chrome Today Tab. I have tested it with countless other URL's and they all seam to work perfectly, just mine that isn't. Are there any known issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your URL is publicly accessible.  In order for it to be displayed in the Chrome Today wiget on iOS, the URL must be successfully crawled by Google's [Physical web service.](https://github.com/google/physical-web/blob/master/web-service/README.md)

Read more about how this works [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/22/how-to-push-messages-without-an-app.html).

Answer (score 1):

It also could be because of the length of your URL. Eddystone™ URL only accepts 17 characters long (except the URL Scheme) URLs. That means, if you have a URL longer than 17 characters, it might be the issue. As I don't know which beacon do you use, I only can guess it maybe cutting the URL after 17th character which breaks the URL and results unsuccessfull crawl by Google's Physical Web Service.

You can use URL shorteners to shorten your URL but when you want to change your content, you will need to reconfigure your beacon too. Instead, you can use [Pushmote URL](https://pushmote.com/eddystone-url). It makes beacon and content management easier.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use a secure URL (i.e. https:// ) as the Physical Web Service will only recognize secure URLs. Also, It can take a few hours for your beacon to be recognized and display in the Physical Web app the first time around. Make sure to keep your URL under 17 bytes by using the shortening codes and a URL shortener like git.io or bit.lt, etc.